# Am I able to change URL using Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I am thinking to have a web page using only Silverlight.

Is it possible to generate links using only Silverlight? So one person can paste a URL at browser and it will direct access one UserControl for example? If not, what can you suggest?

Edit: I want to do something like a forum.

Thanks

Comment: Next time, please show us what you did so far. This is usually considered a bad question on SO because it shows no research effort at all.

Comment: I am sorry. I know my question isn't showing a lot. But I simply didn't know what to search for. I didn't know what keyword to use.

Comment: No problem ;-) All of us learn on the way, this is absolutely no problem if your next question will do better ;-)

Comment: As the guy who answered the question - I'm not really sure if it is put on hold for the right reasons. It's clearly not a broad question - hence my 2-line answer. The only criticism I can think of that it's not well-phrased and the title is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is called a [navigation application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180767%28v=vs.91%29.aspx).

The wizard in Visual Studio (see the link) will get you started.

Comment: oh great. I will check it!